# Vastly different load times for "import tensorflow" in python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm experiencing some great variation in the load times for the tensorflow library in python.

```
python -X importtime -c "import tensorflow" 2> tf1.log
python -X importtime -c "import tensorflow" 2> tf2.log
```

Analyzing the logs with tuna shows the second run is almost twice as fast:

```
tuna tf1.log
```

[image]

```
tuna tf2.log
```

[image]

Why are the load times so different? Is this a cache issue? At first I thought it might have something to do with pyc files but I didnt notice any new pyc files  after the first run.

Comment: Such great analysis. You should ask it in their github

Comment: The OS might have a lot to do here, it can cache files and shared libraries (like DLLs that are loaded by python.exe) in main memory